# Can you test the target configuration in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, settings

I'm working on a project with multiple team members and there is a constant issue where, just for testing purposes, we need to change the General Settings of each target (like the display name, bundle identifier and signing configuration). The issue with this is that sometimes the developers commit this temporary changes to the repo and this messes up with the Lane.

I would like to write some kind of unit tests to avoid this but since the Tests target has its own configuration I haven't find a way of accessing each of the other targets config. I was wondering if I should try parsing the plist file to check the properties but I don't know if there is any other better way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to deal with this is to have all default General Settings info in another branch. Also, for all members working on the same feature branch, they should have the same settings info for that branch.